# How to set DataGrid(Windows Community Toolkit) ItemSource in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

The DataGrid have 2 Columns.Each Column have Different CellTemplate.

Column 1 Cell Template :

```
 <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:ManagePicklistDataGridRangeColumnCellModel">
      <RelativePanel Height="14" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
             <TextBlock Name="HeaderTextBlock" Text="{x:Bind RangeText}" FontSize="12" Height="14" LineHeight="14" FontFamily="SegoeUI" Foreground="{ThemeResource DefaultTextColor}"/>
             <FontIcon RelativePanel.RightOf="HeaderTextBlock" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE700;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
      </RelativePanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Column 2 Cell Template :

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="m:ManagePicklistDataGridRangeColumnCellModel">
       <RelativePanel Height="14" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
             <TextBlock Name="HeaderTextBlock" Text="{x:Bind CellText}" FontSize="12" Height="14" LineHeight="14" FontFamily="SegoeUI" Foreground="{ThemeResource DefaultTextColor}"/>
       </RelativePanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I don't know how to create and Columns in DataGrid and bind the TextBlock property in cell Tempalte using ViewModel in C#.How to set ItemSource of DataGrid using ObservableCollection in c#?

Comment: DataGrid Binds using a List. I would start with a static list, then if your data is changing in size, ObservableCollection. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics

Comment: How to bind TextBlock text in code Behind in c#?

Comment: I have 2 different column cell Template . For this case , I don't know how to bind and set ItemSource of DataGrid?

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: How is setting the `ItemsSource`of the `DataGrid` related to your data templates...? What did you try to set the `ItemsSource`?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to bind and set ItemSource of DataGrid?

DataGrid has ItemSource property, you could bind it with your collection, and it could also be set value in the code behind.

Then each `DataGridTemplateColumn` could access Item propety. for example if your Item model has Name and Age property. And current CellTemplate target type is Item, you could set DataGridTemplateColumn binding like the following

```
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Tag="name">
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

> How to bind TextBlock text in code Behind in c#?

You could get each column with tag, then call `GetCellContent` to retrieve cell content. It could update the binding in the code behind by editing content's `DataContext`

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />

 var dataGridTemplateColumn = datagrid.Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Tag?.Equals("name") == true) as DataGridTemplateColumn;    
 var stackpanel = dataGridTemplateColumn.GetCellContent(MyClasses[0]);
 stackpanel.DataContext = "Hello";
```

Comment: what's that MyClasses[0] means?

Comment: Is there any other way to set the cell data using ItemSource Property for two different column cell Template?

Comment: ItemSource is datagrid's property  but not for cell.

Comment: MyClasses[0] means first item of your collection.